# Coleção de objetos c#

Tags: c#, coleção

Galera preciso preencher uma lista que está dentro de outra lista, mas está dando erro.

Segue o código:

```
Promotora = new LojaPromotoraInfo 
            { 
                CodGerente = DBUtil.GetValor<string>(oRow, "CodGerente"), 
                CodLojaPromotora = DBUtil.GetValor<string>(oRow["CodLojaPromotora"]),
                Agente = new List<PropostaAgente>()
                {

                }

            },
```

As propriedades dentro de `Agente` não aparecem porque `Agente` é uma `IList`.

Como posso preenchê-la ?

Obrigado

Comment: seus objetos CodGerente e CodLojaPromotora estão sendo preenchidos corretamente?, Qual linguagem de programação você esta usando?

Comment: Sim estão sendo preenchido corretamente. Estou usando C#

Comment: Ok, você tem uma classe chamada PropostaAgente, essa classe já tem os dados dela? se não no lugar de você fazer o new chame um método que retorno essa classe com seus dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja o exemplo abaixo;

Essa é uma aplicação `webforms`, mas você só precisa entender a parte das classes e o que tem dentro do método `Page_Load`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var addlista = new List<PropostaAgente>();

            var lista1 = new PropostaAgente()
            {
                Campo1 = "Campo1",
                Campo2 = "Campo2",
            };

            addlista.Add(lista1);

            var Promotora = new LojaPromotoraInfo
            {
                CodGerente = "CodGerente",
                CodLojaPromotora = "CodLojaPromotora",
                Agente = addlista,
            };

            var teste = Promotora;
        }
    }

    public class LojaPromotoraInfo
    {
        public List<PropostaAgente> Agente { get; internal set; }
        public string CodGerente { get; internal set; }
        public string CodLojaPromotora { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class PropostaAgente
    {
        public string Campo1 { get; internal set; }
        public string Campo2 { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Você pode trocar o `addlista` por um método que retorne essa lista ou só informa a lista se você já tiver ela.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda